# Synchronize state in fire-and-forget environment

Tags: asynchronous, network-programming, state, data-synchronization

I'm exchanging data via bluetooth messaging since I need to be able to communicate between devices even if they are offline. I'm not sure if specifics are that important but I'm developing a Flutter application and use the [flutter_nearby_connections](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nearby_connections) package for that.

What is important is that I'm in a fire-and-forget environment such that after I have sent a message, I don't know if the message was received or not. This makes it difficult for me to ensure that 2 clients that are connected to each other have a synchronized state.

In my specific case I have an order that only 1 client may edit at the same time. Other clients can only access this order in a read-only state. At some point I need to transfer this ownership of the order from 1 client to another while offline. Hence the use of bluetooth messaging.

My problem is that in order to transmit ownership of an order both of the involved clients need to fully ensure that their state is fully synchronized so that only 1 client has ownership at the same time.

I've been trying to send acknowledgments to ensure that a target client has received the sent data. But since I never know if the acknowledgment message was actually received, I always end up in an infinite-acknowledgment loop when I try to finalize the order transmission.

Say I want to transmit ownership of the order from Client A to Client B.

I can send the order data to Client B and then wait for an acknowledgement from Client B. If Client A receives an acknowledgment from Client B, Client A knows that Client B now has all the data.

But after Client B has sent the acknowledgement, it doesn't know if Client A has ever received it and can't assume ownership yet. Client A also can't relinquish ownership for this reason.

So Client A could send an acknowledgement of Client B's acknowledgement. But then Client A doesn't know if that was ever received. And so on and so forth.

What way is there to ensure a synchronized ownership state between two clients in a fire-and-forget environment?